# Puppetter : Get a link in a body

Tags: url, text, hyperlink, puppeteer

I've a link in a body like that :

```
      "uri": "https://dispatch-nvidia.digitalriver.com/v1/shoppers/me/products/5438795200/inventory-status",
      "availableQuantityIsEstimated": "false",
      "productIsInStock": "true",
      "productIsAllowsBackorders": "false",
      "productIsTracked": "true",
      "requestedQuantityAvailable": "true",
      "status": "PRODUCT_INVENTORY_OUT_OF_STOCK",
      "statusIsEstimated": "false"
```

I want the url,  how to do that ?
I've try `let bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);`

But don't work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you give a bit more of an example of what you did and a wider view of the page code of the page you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody know ?
I've try with Regex

```
const regex = /(https?:\/\/)(\s)?(www\.)?(\s?)(\w+\.)*([\w\-\s]+\/)*([\w-]+)\/?/gm;
```

Without success ...

Edit : Find the solution :

```
    const bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    console.log(bodyHTML)
    const regex = /(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm;

const found2 = String(bodyHTML.match(regex));
```